# Writing data from a Python List and a Dictionary to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, dictionary

Assume `mydict` is unique based on each list item:

```
 mylist = ['li1', 'li2']
 mydict =  {'key1': 'value1','key2': 'value2','key3': 'value3}
```

I want to write this stracture in a `CSV` file:

```
ListItem, key1, key2, key3
li1, value1, value2, value3
li2, value1, value2, value3
```

This is a sample of how I try to do this; but my code overwrites the first line with each iteration, and I do not know how to write the list item in the first column. Could you give me a hand, please?

```
import pandas as pd
import random


def CreateDict(li):
    dict = {}
    dict['x'] = random.randrange(1, li)  #25
    dict['y'] = random.randrange(1, li)  #27
    print(dict)
    return dict

mylist = [10, 20, 30]
for li in mylist:
    mydict = CreateDict(li)
    df = pd.DataFrame([mydict])
    df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

I get this as an output:

```
x,y
25,27
```

Comment: In the for loop the data frame and the csv file get overwritten with each iteration. Therefore the data frame as well as the csv file will only contain the dict created in the last iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try **[`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys)** to generate data dictionary, then create a dataframe from this `data` dictionary and use **[`DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)** to save as a `csv` file:

```
data = dict.fromkeys(mylist, mydict)
pd.DataFrame(data).T.rename_axis('ListItem').to_csv('foo.csv')
```

EDIT: If you would like to create unique dictionary per item in `mylist` you can use:

```
data = {li:CreateDict(li) for li in mylist}
pd.DataFrame(data).T.rename_axis('ListItem').to_csv('foo.csv')
```

---

```
# foo.csv

ListItem,key1,key2,key3
li1,value1,value2,value3
li2,value1,value2,value3
```

Comment: Thanks, I use the code in the loop, but the dictionary values are not changing in the CSV file.

Comment: @Flodude You don't have to use the code in the loop

Comment: @Flodude Not sure but i guess you want `pd.DataFrame({li:CreateDict(li) for li in mylist}).T.rename_axis('ListItem').to_csv('foo.csv')`..One more thing don't use `dict` as an identifier its reserved `keyword` in python.

Comment: It works but it re-run the CreateDict function!

Comment: @Flodude  Can you please elaborate `re-run the CreateDict function`?

Comment: I suggested an edit. If you think it makes sense, confirm with possible corrections.

Comment: @Flodude Accepted and improved your edit.

Answer (score 2):

Working on your existing solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import random


def CreateDict(li):
    dict = {}
    dict['x'] = random.randrange(1, li)  #25
    dict['y'] = random.randrange(1, li)  #27
    print(dict)
    return dict

mylist = [10, 20, 30]
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['x', 'y'])
for li in mylist:
    mydict = CreateDict(li)
    df=pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([mydict])])

df['mylist']=mylist
result=df[['mylist', 'x', 'y']]
result.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
mylist  x  y
   10   6  3
   20   8  2
   30   7  4
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should create a dictionary outside the function, add items in loop and write only at the end.
With your code you're writing 3 times the same file and you see only the last row.

For index you should set index=True.

Here the code. Hope I help you!

```
import pandas as pd
import random

my_dict = {
    'key1':[],
    'key2':[],
    'key3':[]
}

def AddToDict(li):
    my_dict['key1'].append(random.randrange(1, li))
    my_dict['key2'].append(random.randrange(1, li))
    my_dict['key3'].append(random.randrange(1, li))

mylist = [10, 20, 30]
for li in mylist:
    AddToDict(li)

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)  # Here
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't write the list item in the first row.